# How many ways are there to select a collection of 10 coins chosen from very large bags of coins with face values 100, 200, 500 and 1000?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to select a collection of 10 coins chosen from very large bags of coins with face values 100, 200, 500 and 1000?

> If you consider your equation $+++=10$, with $x\geq 0$, $y\geq 0$, $z\geq 0$, $w\geq 0$b but I don't know if  this is the right way to find the solution

Comment: Why? I don't understand

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Answer (score 0):

By ["stars and bars"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) the number is

$$N=\binom{10+4-1}{10}=286.$$

Answer (score 0):

I would first simplify this problem by saying we are picking 14 coins, with at least one of each denomination; this has the same number of possibilities, but I think can more easily be calculated.

Imagine we are deciding which of each type of coin we will choose by visualising the 14 coins lined up; we then need to place three separators in the gaps between them, the separators themselves being identical, but the number of coins counted from the left to the first seperator gives the number of say 100 valued coins, then between the second and third the number of 200, etc., and from the last seperator to the end of the coins, the number of 1000 valued coins.

So this is $\binom{13}{3}$, since there are 13 gaps and 3 separators. Note that two separators can't be in the same gap (which would correspond to not picking any of one of the denominations). Sorry if I didn't explain that very well, it's late!